# Queue tasks with Hangfire on a different server to where they are executed?

Tags: c#, hangfire, webapi

We are creating a website using propriety closed source CMS software, and I need to run a long-running task on the webserver to import products into the store (with code built into our CMS), but I'd like too queue these long running tasks on a different server, is this possible?

for example:

Server 1 :

```
// not shown: set "DbConnection" as our sql connection somehow?
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!"));
```

Server 2:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("DbConnection");
_backgroundJobServer = new BackgroundJobServer();
```

so that "Hello, World1" would be executed on Server 2 instead of server 1. Is this possible?

Comment: That's exactly the point addressed by hangfire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only create background job servers on Server2, but **not** on Server1. If both Server1 and Server2 use the same storage settings, you can schedule jobs on Server1 but they are only executed on Server2.